# Find a Lipschitz constant for $f(x) = x^{1/3}; -1\le x \le 1 $ on the region indicated, or prove there is none.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a Lipschitz constant for $f(x) = x^{1/3}; -1\le x \le 1 $ on the region indicated, or prove there is none.

i got to f(x) is lipschitz if there exists C such that $|x^{1/3} - y^{1/3}| \le C|x-y|$ for all x, y.....

From here on, i am struck...could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Show that if $L$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f$, then $|f'(x)| \le L$ for all $x$. Then compute $\sup_x |f'(x)|$.

Better still, draw a picture :-).

Comment: do you have any online graphing websites allowing for drawing a function like this?

Comment: You can plot functions on Wolfram Alpha for free. Try entering the text: "plot y=x^(1/3), x=-1..1"

Comment: Yes, try desmos.com. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/irls6jii9i

Comment: However, note that the function is odd, and you can pick a few points and try plotting by hand (gasp!).

Comment: i just found out that the derivative of this function goes to infinity when x approaches 0....so there is not Lipschitz constant for this function right?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: do u think based on the requirement of this question, I can just say as x approaches 0, the derivative of this function go to infinity ....so no lipschitz constant is enought?

Comment: I don't know what your instructor wants. I would follow my directions in the question above (follows from the limit in the definition of $f'$), and show that the derivative is unbounded near zero, hence no Lipschitz constant exist on the interval in question.

Comment: I can see from graph as x approaches 0, f'(x) >>> infinity...could you show me how to show it by word in proof format?

Comment: Just follow my directions...

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0} 1/3x^{-2/3}$$ what is next ?

Comment: I am happy to help, but you need to do some work. What do you not understand?

Comment: I am wondering do I need to use real analysis argument or just plain calculus limit definition. What do you think?

Comment: They are the same? You have $\left| {  f(x+h)-f(x) \over h} \right| \le L$, hence it is true in the limit.

Comment: I am thinking about $\epsilon, \delta$ argument for real analysis

Comment: what do you think about the following: Fix M > 0. Then, |x| = |x - 0| < M^{-3/2} implies |x^{-2/3}| > M....So  $$\lim_{x\to 0} 1/3x^{-2/3} = \infty$$?

Comment: That looks fine, but again I do not know what level your instructor expects answers. For example, you tagged differential equations, which is were the Lipschitz stuff is coming from (I presume), so proving that the above limit would seem to be something that could be taken for granted at that level. So, I really can't judge what is an appropriate answering level for you.

Comment: I do want to know the definition of limit that you have above...could you expand that?

Comment: I don't know which limit you are referring to.

Comment: $|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}| \le L$

Comment: I'm confused. The usual definition of $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x) \over h}$. If you take absolute values you can bound this with $L$.

Comment: could you show this in step?

Comment: Show what? I just gave a definition. This is getting a bit frustrating.

Comment: I mean how to use the definition of limit to show  $$\lim_{x\to 0} 1/3x^{-2/3}$$  goes to infinity

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: you can make $\frac13x^{-2/3}=\frac1{3x^{2/3}}$ as big as you want by making $x$ close to $0$.

Comment: @robjohn: I understand that....how to prove it though

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: pick any $M>0$. For any $|x|\lt\frac1{(3M)^{3/2}}$, $\frac13x^{-2/3}\gt M$.